# shred multiple hard drives

Tags: shredding

I have a bunch of disks needing shredding. I also have 6 ports for hard drives on my PC. Shred, even running with brief options takes a while. I read the manpage for shred, but I saw no way to shred multiple hard drives concurrently.
Is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: You could just run multiple instances of shred concurrently (e.g in different VTs / Terminals), one for each hard drive, or am I missing something ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run `shred` in the background. For example, if the disks are `/dev/sdu` `/dev/sdv`, `/dev/sdw`, `/dev/sdx`, `/dev/sdy`, and `/dev/sdz`:

```
for d in sdu sdv sdw sdx sdy sdz ; do
    shred --your-options-here /dev/$d 2>&1 >shred.$d.log &
done
jobs
```