# shred command all disks

Tags: 19.04, shredding

I have a couple of computers that have multiple drives in them.
I have Ubuntu on a USB drive that and right now using the shred option I need to manually run the shred command for each HDD/SSD myself.

Is it possible that it does that shred automatically for all the drives that it has, except for the USB that Ubuntu is running from?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/786140/shred-multiple-hard-drives

Comment: that way you know the disk letters already is there not a script that finds these automaticly

Comment: get the disks **list** with something like `lsblk -S | grep disk | cut -d " " -f 1` then run the referred `for` loop against this **list**

Answer (score 0):

Shred all physical disks?

Get the disks list with something like `lsblk -S | grep disk | cut -d " " -f 1` then run the a loop against this list

```
#!/bin/bash
## get disks list
DisksList=$(lsblk -S | grep disk | cut -d " " -f 1)
## Loop from https://askubuntu.com/a/786171/77093
for d in $DisksList ; do
    ## shred --your-options-here /dev/$d 2>&1 >shred.$d.log &
    # example of a shred command options, no log, one thread
    shred -vfz -n 1 /dev/$d
done
```